# What is new name of load_defaults() function in mysql c api?

Tags: mysql, c, mysql-connector-c

What is new name of load_defaults() function in mysql c api?

I tried the following code from this link (http://www.kitebird.com/mysql-book/ch06-2ed.pdf). I am using MySQL 5.7 and Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7/64bit. The load_defaults() function no more exists. There is no documentation on it. What is the new name of load_defaults() function?

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <my_sys.h> //#include <my_getopt.h>

static const char *client_groups[] = { "show_argv","client", NULL };

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  int i;

    printf("Original argument vector:\n");  for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)      printf("arg %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);

    my_init();  my_load_defaults("my", client_groups, &argc, &argv);

    printf("Modified argument vector:\n");  for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)      printf("arg %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);         exit(0); }
```

Comment: Could be named `my_load_defaults()`?  There was apparently a race condition with `load_defaults()`, based on [this info old bug information](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=40552). Search the page for `load_defaults` to follow the details.

Comment: In mariadb it has been renamed to `mariadb_load_defaults`, but it's implementation can not be found. I got `undefined reference to 'mariadb_load_defaults'` when linking.

Answer (score 0):

`load_defaults` was never meant to be used outside of the client lib. It had therefore been removed from the library exports. I assumed this would still be the case, but then I found: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25535, which seems to indicate this function has been renamed and re-exported. Didn't check this myself, though .

Comment: MySQL Developers didnt mention the substitute for this function in their manual. Where to find it? It is also no more in my_sys.h header file.

Comment: Then my assumption seems still be correct. It's no longer available.

Comment: What is the solution instead of using load_defaults() on 09-12-2017?

Comment: There is no solution. I talked with the responsible people. This function is considered to be internal. It's still exported by the client lib, but meant to be used by MySQL software only (the declaration has been removed from the public C API and is exposed only by an internal header). It shouldn't be used outside, can change at any time and no promise is made that it will do what you expect. Better get away without it.